# ./tezos-client activate: error Unrecognized command

Tags: faucet, activate

I am stuck when getting Tezos from faucet https://faucet.tzalpha.net/ :

```
./tezos-client activate account bob with tz1YdaJWrDdHz4qfVEhPEs7f5EBy4DE2Fzv1.json
Disclaimer: ...

Error:
  Unrecognized command.
  Try using the man command to get more information.
```

Seems like `tezos-client activate` command do not exist...

I build from source yesterday with doc https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am synced :
```
./tezos-client bootstrapped
Disclaimer:...
Current head: BL8gY2QxKSPA (timestamp: 2018-09-08T22:03:12-00:00, validation: 2020-10-28T09:15:10-00:00)
Bootstrapped.
```

And I got an account: ./tezos-client gen keys bob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `tezos-client activate` does not exist on mainnet. Are you positive that you launched your node against one of the test networks? The faucet is only for the test networks.

You may need to repeat your node setup and pass `--network carthagenet` when starting it.

Comment: You are right, this line was missing for the documentation:
"tezos-node config init --network carthagenet"

I was probably then targeting mainnet, but error message was not clear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Your node is not sync'ed.** (I agree that the error output doesn't describe the problem)

```
(timestamp: 2018-09-08T22:03:12-00:00, validation: 2020-10-28T09:15:10-00:00).
             ^^^^^                                      ^^^^^^
          current block                              Target block
```

Comment: Ahh ok thanks, I did not notice. I was following the doc: "tezos-client bootstrapped
This call will hang and return only when the node is synchronized." And as the command return with message "bootstrapped", I thought I was synced. :-)